# Non-blocking synchronization using System.Threading.Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Is there a way to benefit from the advantages of non-blocking thread synchronization, such as that described [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Nonblocking_Synchronization), but while using the `System.Threading.Task` objects in the current .Net framework versions?

What i'm looking for essentially is changing this code

```
new Task(() =>
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        ...            
    }
});
```

into something that won't block the threadpool thread that will be used by the `Task` in performing the operation protected by the lock.

Comment: It's acceptable to block within tasks if the critical section is short-lived and you avoid risks of deadlocks.

Comment: Also, don't use the `Task` constructor explicitly. Use `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead.

Comment: That said, if you're really aiming for a non-blocking implementation, the way to go would be to decompose your algorithm into a series of tasks and continuations.

Comment: I think the article confused you: `Wait()` is most certainly *blocking* synchronization.

Comment: @Douglas: If the `Task` is used for parallel computations, then `StartNew` is fine; but if the `Task` is used for `await`, then `Task.Run` is better.

Comment: @svick: thanks for pointing that out, i removed Monitor.Wait() from the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this using .Net 4.0 TPL, you can use a custom `TaskScheduler`, for example [`LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` from ParallelExtensionsExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx).

If you can use C# 5.0, you could use `await` together with `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()` or [`AsyncLock` from Nito AsyncEx](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncLock&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: .NET 4.5 introduced `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` which includes limited concurrency.

Comment: Nice, i think i like the idea of `AsyncLock`, i'll try to fiddle with it and see how well i can accomplish what i need. The environment i'm working on is C# 5.0, .Net Framework 4.5, portable class library project.